# Bluetooth diagnostics logs on iOS

Tags: ios, logging, bluetooth

I'd like to generate Bluetooth diagnostics logs on iPhone. I've installed Bluetooth Development Profile and I can click on "Save logs". But where can I find them and how can I transfer them to PC?
Preferably without iTunes, as on Windows I have very bad experience with this SW. I'm new to Apple ecosystem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer can be found in the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=bluetooth).

The steps are as follows.

1. Download and install the profile on your device (this can be done through Safari on the device).
2. Restart your device.
3. Reproduce any bluetooth commands you would like to diagnose.
4. Go to Settings > Bluetooth and select Diagnostic Mode
5. Add short description of the problem and tap Save
6. Sync device via iTunes (there doesn't seem to be a way to pull them manually without a rooted device).

Windows 7, 8, and Vista logs can be found at:

```
C:\Users\[Your_User_Name]\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\[Your_Device_Name]\BluetoothDiagnostics\
```

OSX logs can be found at:

```
/Users/[Your_User_name]/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/[Your_Device_Name]/BluetoothDiagnostics/
```

The logs will be saved into timestamped folders like this `Logs-2015.12.8-00.50.55/`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to avoid step 6 (iTunes). I'm already using it that way, I've found the same documentation.

Comment: after iOS10 published, there is a problem to obtain logging profile for iOS9 devices (I found right one only in my downloads history). Current available for download profile is incompatible for iOS9 devices.

Comment: This is old info. For iOS 10, you must use sysdiagnose. Although I can't figure out where the Bluetooth logs are now: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/iOS_Logs/Bluetooth_Logging_Instructions__iPhone_and_Apple_Watch.pdf

Comment: Apparently the logs are no longer separate: "In the iOS 10 logging system, there are no longer separate Bluetooth log files available.

The information is contained in the .logarchive file and can be examined by using the Console app." https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67802